# flutter provider how to notify listeners in a list

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have a list in a provider that takes a custom class that houses two bools called CustomClass.

```
List<CustomClass> MyList = [
CustomClass(bool1 = false, bool2 = false),
CustomClass(bool1 = false, bool2 = false),
CustomClass(bool1 = false, bool2 = false),
CustomClass(bool1 = false, bool2 = false),
CustomClass(bool1 = false, bool2 = false),
];
```

and here is the custom class

```
class CustomClass {
bool bool1;
bool bool2;

void Bool1Toggle(){
bool1 = !bool1;
}
void Bool2Toggle(){
bool2 = !bool2;
}

CustomClass ({required this.bool1, required this.bool2});
}
```

the problem I'm having is when a button in the app is pressed, I want the bool to change so the colour of the button will change.

im running the following code in the onTap of the button:

```
context.read<Provider>().MyList[0].Bool1Toggle();
```

and for the color of the button im using the code:

```
context.watch<Provider>().MyList[0].bool1 ? kwhite : kblack,
```

the problem is the color isnt updating. I ran a print statement on the ontap and the bool is definitely updating when pressed it's just not reflecting this in the colour.

I think it has something to do with the watch statement and the notifylisteners() function in the provider but because the function is housed in the CustomCLass i don't know how to make it notify the listeners.

cheers

Comment: Add  notifyListeners(); in the provider class. The data must update.

Comment: thank you, but where in the provider class do I add the notify listeners? when I put it under the list, I get the following error: The instance member 'notifyListeners' can't be accessed in an initializer.

Comment: is the list is wrote in the provider class?

Comment: yes it is. cheers

Comment: then just add the notifyListeners(); at the end of the class.

Answer (score 0):

1. First extend the CustomClass with ChangeNotifier(from material.dart)
2. For the methods Bool1Toggle and Bool2Toggle, create functions to call them and add the notifyListerners at the end like shown below

```
class MyProvider with ChangeNotifier{
    List<CustomClass>  MyList = [.....]

    void toggleBool1(int index){
        MyList[index].Bool1Toggle();
        notifyListerners();
    }

....do similar for Bool2Toggle
```

3. For evey screen you access the MyProvider data, wrap the component(more specifically the body) with the Consumer widget(from the provider package). This is as shown below.

```
...

body: Consumer<MyProvider>(
//the data(you can call it whatever) in the builder contains information from the MyProvider provider
//for example, MyList, toggleBool1, etc
//you can ignore the child, parameter for now
    builder:(context, data, child){
//assuming this is your page
    return Column(
       children: [
//somewhere in the widget tree
          ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text("toggle bool1"),
          onTap: (){
              data.toggleBool1();
           }),
      ],
    );
   }
),
```

After you have implemented all these changes, hopefully everything should work fine without setState or anything else